# ajax passing the json value to html input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I want to pass the output of my ajax json to my input type textbox. How can i do it. I have this code but my code doesn't work. here it is

my script :

```
function getUserDetails(id) {
         $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo site_url('manager/profile/userDetails/')?>/" + id,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {
                $('#fname').html(data['user_fname']);


          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              //alert('Error get data from ajax');
          }
        });
```

my html input type tag :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use .val() to add the value into the input. Try the following:

```
 $('#fname').val(data['user_fname']);
```

also you need to ensure that that the input can handle this value and and is expecting.

Comment: waiting for 4 mins sir